# How can I add more space to my non adjacent Linux partitions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

So I'm using Kubuntu and I ran out of space in / and /home. I went to my dual boot Windows one and freed 150GB. After this it came to my surprise that I couldn't add more volume to my before mentioned partitions cause they are not adjacent.

Could anyone please tell me how to do this?

The one with 23GB is the / partition and the 66GB one the /home. The 7 GB one is the Swap. As you can see the 150gb unallocated space is not adjacent to my partitions.

[image: This is how my disc looks]

Help is much appreciated

Comment: For me to make the best recommendation, I need to see a screenshot of `gparted` in Ubuntu. Thanks. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I wouldn't do anything unless you have solid backups, preferably a clone of your whole system. That said, you could cut the 66G partition and paste it into the 146G unoccupied space, then expand it. Then expand the 23G partition into the hole the 66G partition left.

Comment: @heynnema I edited the post with the new screenshot, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p6 to the right to make the partition ~50G
- **move** /dev/nvme0n1p7 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/nvme0n1p7 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: after clicking the Apply icon in try Kubuntu what do I do? I remove the usb and reboot?

Comment: @enekovalero Yes, after the moves/resizes are done. Just reboot. It'll prompt you to remove the USB. Congrats!

Comment: I'm sorry, one last thing. After doing all the changes and before clicking apply I have to click swapon to my swap partition, don't I? thank you!

Comment: @enekovalero No, just reboot after letting Apply do its work. Swap will be active then.

Comment: Excellent answer, well written. I'll bookmark this