# gparted extend partition with free space from non-adjacent partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual-booting Windows and Linux installed and I am running out of space on *nvme0n1p5*  `/` root partition. So I want to extend this partition with space either from *nvme0n1p3* (78G unused) or swap partition *nvme0n1p8* (10G total). But both of them are not neighbor partition of *nvme0n1p5*. There are small partitions in between them (p4 and p7), used for Windows recovery and `/boot` partition I think.

So even though I shrink *nvme0n1p3* and make available some unallocated space, I can't merge it into *nvme0n1p5* by dragging the slider left to cover the unallocated space.

Is there any way to extend the root partition without requiring a full clean install?

[image]

Comment: You are mentioning `/root` which is **not** the `/` or root partition, but a directory used to hold *root* user files which is usually only KB in size.  `/root` and the root directory `/` are different things.

Comment: You can only expand a partition to use *contiguous* space, so if the space has a partition (p4) between it, that partition will need to be moved first.. (*so the space is next to the partition you want to expand*) which may have implications on other systems depending on how *the moved partition* is actually used.  Why you plan out what you'll need before you install your OS.

Comment: @guiverc sorry for the confusion, it should be `/` the root partition. I was following the instructions from your linked answer, have tried gparted on a live CD, but I'm not sure how to do that with non-adjacent partitions.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to do a reinstall and redo the whole partition, hopefully it can be organized in a better way this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add more space to my non adjacent Linux partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289133/how-can-i-add-more-space-to-my-non-adjacent-linux-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is shrink p3. Move p4 to the left. Move p5 to the left, so you end up with with the unallocated space to the right of it. Then enlarge p5.
I would not go through the hassle of adding the 57 Mb unallocated  space (located at the end of the disk), because it is so small.
Make backups first.